# Restrict access to MVC route in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'd like to restrict access to the routes in an MVC site via IIS to an intranet site using Windows Authentication.

I'm aware this can be done via the Authorize attribute on a controller or action but I'd prefer to use the Authorization Rules feature of IIS 7.5 such that a GUI (inet manager) provides admins with the ability to grant/restrict access on an adhoc basis. Is this possible?

e.g. in a default routing configuration lock down http://server/admin (which is authenticated with Windows Authentication) without adding an Authorize attribute to the AdminController class or AdminController's Index action but only via the IIS Manager post deploy.

Comment: I know you had mentioned that you don't want to use the Authorize attribute. Any specific reason that you don't want to grant a group access and then simply manage who is in that group? eg: [Authorize(Roles = @"MVCAdminAccess")]

Comment: At design/code time I don't know the group names. They're managed & maintained outside of my control and it would be nice to have a gui that controls all of this rather than 'hardcoding'.

Comment: Who says you would need to hardcode it? There is no reason why you couldn't pull the group form a web config?

Comment: It's an attribute so values must be constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick to the authorize attribute for best practices. The problem with Authorization Rules is that it is URL based and in MVC multiple urls can at times go to the same place that's why it's recommended you secure at the controller level if possible and not via URL.

Comment: True, but I would think most site maps would be defined and segregated in a manner where URL based security would be a perfectly acceptable solution. Additionally I don't like the idea of me defining the group in code (specifically the domain but also the group itself if infrastructure conventions change). Securing it via IIS seemed a reasonable approach.